# Regex to parse a phrase with wildcards

Tags: regex, parsing, python-2.7

Just learning regex and I'm trying to parse a phrase with dates from a string that matches the format "from * to *" where * can be any string. For instance, given an example string: "I'm available from March 1 to May 31",

I'd like to be able to parse out "from March 1 to May 31" because it matches the "from * to *" specification where *.

Any tips on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what language are you using? Regexps differ between languages.

Comment: Show example of string which need to parse

Comment: dates in *any* format using only regex? what are you, crazy?

Comment: I'm currently using Python. Thanks. It does not necessarily need to be in any format, I'd just like a general approach to just parse a string that starts with "from .. to.. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is:

```
\bfrom\b(?:.*?)\bto\s+(?:January|February|March|April|Mai|Ju[nl]y|August|(?:(?:Octo|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)em)ber))\s+\d+
```